# Where are domain genesis transactions (creating trustee DIDs) in Hyperledger Indy getting_started example?

Tags: hyperledger, hyperledger-indy, indy-node

I'm running the Hyperledger Indy example at https://github.com/hyperledger/indy-sdk/blob/master/docs/getting-started/run-getting-started.md

I see there are pool genesis transactions created with `generate_indy_pool_transactions` . But I don't see any domain genesis transactions to create initial Trustee DIDs. I assume there are always initial Trustee DIDs created. Where are they in the example?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think I found the domain transactions, they are in `domain_transactions_genesis` in the `sandbox` and was generated there somehow